# GVIM: diff against the saved file in Windows

Tags: windows, gvim, diff

Under Linux, I diff the currently open file against the saved file like so:

```
:w !diff % -
```

Is there any way to do this under Windows in GVIM?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DiffOrig command will do this. See

```
:help :DiffOrig
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you Gary! I think that I need to start going through some of your old posts!